# How to make a table view just use one query in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in database like this

```
NAME    |GENDER|
JONH    |MALE
NGUYEN  |MALE
TRAN    |FAMALE
THUY    |FAMALE
LINH    |FAMALE
```

And now, How can I make a sql query for get result like this:

```
GENDER  |NUMBER
FAMALE  |3
MALE    |2
```

Comment: Any SQL tutorial should teach this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select GENDER, COUNT(*) AS NUMBER FROM Students
GROUP BY GENDER
```